# How to cast a column when using $this->db->like?

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

In my application there is a dataTable , so there is the search mechanism , and one of the columns in the dataTable has an int datatype. Here is how I made the server-side search :

```
private function _get_datatables_query()
{

    $this->db->from($this->table);

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column
    {
        if($_POST['sSearch']) // if datatable send POST for search
        {    
            if($i===0) // first loop
            {
                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                $this->db->like($item.'::varchar', $_POST['sSearch']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->or_like($item.'::varchar', $_POST['sSearch']);
            }

            if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['iSortCol_0'])) // here order processing
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['iSortCol_0']], $_POST['sSortDir_0']);
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }

}
```

At runtime I got error because the cast is written like this : `"some_column::varchar" like '%search_data%'` ; it should be like this : `"some_column"::varchar like '%search_data%'`

So how to cast the column when calling `$this->db->like`  ?

Comment: why you are casting it to varchar

Comment: because the column's datatype is bigint and the database is postgresql.

Comment: Is it for searching from both end ?  as %value% in mysql ?

Comment: yes it is the syntax `like '%value%'` , but the syntax is generic because I loop an array containing all the columns to be considered in the search !

Comment: You can use $this->db->like($item, $_POST['sSearch'],'both'); to search from both ends in CI query format. I am not sure about use of casting

Comment: it does not work ! I got `The operator does not exist : bigint ~~ text`

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick by making a `to_char` when the column is the concerned one :

```
    foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column
    {
        if($_POST['sSearch']) // if datatable send POST for search
        {

            if($i===0) // first loop
            {
                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                if ($item == 'ladate')
                    $item = "ltrim(to_char(ladate,'99999999'))";
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['sSearch']);
            }
            else
            {
                if ($item == 'ladate')
                    $item = "ltrim(to_char(ladate,'99999999'))";
                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['sSearch']);
            }

            if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
    }
```